# Trying to the change the search button behaviour

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm trying to do that the search button in the management view of the pieces could search partial words. I mean, now if you have a piece with "test" name, you can search looking for the "test" name, but you don't find it with if you put only "te" in you search.

I'm trying to change the manager-modal.js in apostrophe-pieces, but I don't really know how to change it. How can I modify for doing this?

That's the search I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: This would probably be best handled as a PR to the apostrophe module, because even if we switch up manager-modal to submit the "autocomplete" parameter rather than the "search" one there is still logic on the server side that's expecting "search." But there are UX questions to be answered first, because autocomplete is only aware of high-priority words, like words in titles and tags. We probably need a system that does autocomplete while you type but does a more complete search when you press enter or submit. I suggest you open a github issue to talk about it.

Comment: Finally, I added a new filter that looks for any piece that contains the word in "high-priority".For example, when I look for "test", it will show the piece "test", the piece "testing" and the piece "untesting", all the pieces than contains the word that you have looked for.



I don't know if this would be a possible PR. In any case, if this filter is not suitable for your interests, I could change the filter to an other one that you think is more appropiate to the search modal.